# How to use React.memo to not re render when a new element is added to the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a parent component that renders a list of text messages. Before I used `React.memo`, every time I enter a key all of the message components would re-render.

After I use `React.memo`, it solved this problem.

However, when I press enter to enter a new message, all of the previous message components re render again.

```
function MsgList({ api_res}) {
  return api_res.map((msg, index) => {

    return (
      <MemoMsg
        key={msg.timestamp}
        // other args
      />
    );
  });
}

const MemoMsgList = React.memo(MsgList);
```

So the idea is that whenever a new message is entered, it uses the previous messages and only has to compute this message.

How can this be done?

Comment: How is the new message getting into the list? From an API call or something else?

Comment: yeah, it is an API call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.memo` is used for unnecessary renderings. Rerendering components upon prop or state change is the core concept of react.

But in your case since you are using `api_res.map` and already having `key` prop, those `MemoMsg` components should not rerender, they should [be reconciliated.](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/reacts-reconciliation-algorithm/)

Check `msg.timestamp`, maybe it does not return a stable key.

in case something else from `MemoMsg` causing rerendering, wrap `MemoMsg` component with `React.Memo`

Comment: you are right, there are a couple of objects passed into `Msg` that were getting `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`